# Compiling Hydra Using Cygwin

Tags: gcc, compilation, cygwin, hydra

I am trying to compile Hydra using Cygwin. But I am unable to do So..

./configure command gives the following results.

$ ./configure

Starting hydra auto configuration ...

Checking for openssl (libssl, libcrypto, ssl.h, sha.h) ...
                                                       ... found
Checking for idn (libidn.so) ...
                             ... found
Checking for curses (libcurses.so / term.h) ...
                                            ... found, color output enabled
Checking for pcre (libpcre.so, pcre.h) ...
                                       ... found
Checking for Postgres (libpq.so, libpq-fe.h) ...
                                             ... found
Checking for SVN (libsvn_client-1 libapr-1.so libaprutil-1.so) ...
                                                               ... NOT found, module svn disabled
Checking for firebird (libfbclient.so) ...
                                       ... NOT found, module firebird disabled
Checking for MYSQL client (libmysqlclient.so, math.h) ...
                                                      ... found
Checking for AFP (libafpclient.so) ...
                                   ... NOT found, module Apple Filing Protocol disabled - Apple sucks anyway
Checking for NCP (libncp.so / nwcalls.h) ...
                                         ... NOT found, module NCP disabled
Checking for SAP/R3 (librfc/saprfc.h) ...
                                      ... NOT found, module sapr3 disabled
Get it from http://www.sap.com/solutions/netweaver/linux/eval/index.asp
Checking for libssh (libssh/libssh.h) ...
                                      ... NOT found, module ssh disabled
Get it from http://www.libssh.org
Checking for Oracle (libocci.so libclntsh.so / oci.h and libaio.so) ...
                                                                    ... NOT found, module Oracle disabled
Get basic and sdk package from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html
Checking for GUI req's (pkg-config, gtk+-2.0) ...
                                              ... found
Checking for Android specialities ...
                                  ... rindex() found
                                  ... RSA_generate_key() found
Checking for secure compile option support in gcc ...
                                                  Compiling... yes
                                                  Linking... no

Hydra will be installed into .../bin of: /usr/local
  (change this by running ./configure --prefix=path)

Writing Makefile.in ...

Cygwin detected, if compilation fails just update your installation.

Windres found, will attach icons to hydra cygwin executables

now type "make"

After make and install I get hydra.exe

Then after copying all the needed dlls to the hydra.exe folder when the run the application.. I get the following error.

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) click OK to close the application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use `gdb hydra.exe` by compiling it in debug maybe ?
You could try `cygcheck hydra.exe` to look if your exe isn't lacking of a library. If so install it via setup or else.

Comment: Is there no way to install not found modules automatically?

Comment: I don't think so. Look at [cygcheck options](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html). But you could still look at the libraries missing and install them via the setup.exe/